# Associates of (x + 1) in Q[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Definition of Associates for commutative rings with identity: Let *a, b* $\in$ *R*. Then *b* is an associate of *a* if *b* = *au* for some unit *u* of *R*.

With this definition, I am able to conclude that the associates of $(x+1)$ in $\mathbb{Q}$[*x*] are $(x+1)$ $\cdot$ *u* where *u* $\in$ *R*. Thus, is it sufficient to say that $(x^2 + x)$ is an associate of $(x+1)$ in $\mathbb{Q}$[*x*] since $(x^2 + x) = x(x + 1)$?

Comment: $(x^2+x)=(x+1)\cdot x$ indicates $x^2+x$ is an associate of $x+1$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ if $x$ is a unit in $\mathbb Q[x]$, but is $x$ a unit in $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Answer (score 3):

A unit in $\mathbb Q[x]$ is an invertible element of $\mathbb Q[x]$ i.e. $f \in \mathbb Q[x]$ is a unit if there exists $g \in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $fg = 1$, where $1$ is the constant polynomial with value $1$.

From here, it is easy to see that the only units in $\mathbb Q[x]$ are the non-zero constant polynomials : because if $\deg f > 0$ then $\deg fg \geq \deg f > 0$ so $fg \neq 1$. Therefore, $f$ is a constant polynomial, and obviously then $f = c \implies g = \frac 1c$ works whenever $c \neq 0$.

Thus, the associates of $x+1$ are of the form $c(x+1)$ for any $c \in \mathbb Q, c \neq 0$. Examples would be $2(x+1)$, or $\frac 12(x+1)$ or $-\pi(x+1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! So for example, (x-1) would not be an associate of (x+1) in $\mathbb{Q}$[*x*] since (x-1) cannot be written as the form *c*(*x* + 1) but (-x-1) would be an associate of (x+1) in $\mathbb{Q}$[*x*] since (-x-1) can be written in the form -1(x+1) correct?

Comment: Correct, that is right.